# Set UTF-8 display for Git GUI differences window

Tags: git, utf-8, diff, git-diff, git-gui

I can't remember how I made Git GUI to display UTF-8 encoded differences correctly. Also I can't find the guide in search engines.

Now I need to do this at new workplace. Could you write down instructions?

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Please give more details about your setup - host OS type and version. If this is Linux or Mac, please show what `locale` says.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
# Global setting for all you repositories
> git config --global gui.encoding utf-8

# For one repository only
> git config gui.encoding utf-8
```

Or from the GUI window:

Edit -> Options... -> Default File Contents Encoding -> Change

and select "Unicode (UTF-8)"

In the Options, you'll see that there are two panel, the one on the right is for all repositories, the one on the left for the local repository.

Comment: Hm. This does not work for me... :( Are there more things that can be wrong, than this setting?

Comment: @mikew Yes. This option specifies the default encoding of file contents for both git-gui and gitk. See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-guiencoding)

Comment: in my case i have to restart gui to make the option effect.

Answer (score 2):

The file content encoding is clarified with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021):

See [commit 1e93770](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e93770888d3e71422f9f8defab216f1ebf977c3), [commit fd680bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd680bc5586ab7c846e03e181e033dbc36cc7d5d) (27 Aug 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bfe37f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfe37f3dc5a7750dd77c571ada91112b4389ffae), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e93770888d3e71422f9f8defab216f1ebf977c3): use "**character encoding**" to refer to commit-object encoding
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The word "**encoding**" can mean a lot of things (e.g., base64 or quoted-printable encoding in emails, HTML entities, URL encoding, and so on).
>
> The documentation for `i18n.commitEncoding` and `i18n.logOutputEncoding` uses the phrase "**character encoding**" to make this more clear.
>
> Let's use that phrase in other places to make it clear what kind of encoding we are talking about.
>
> This patch covers the **`gui.encoding`** option, as well as the `--encoding` option for `git-log`, etc (in this latter case, I word-smithed the sentence a little at the same time).
> That, coupled with the mention of `iconv` in the `--encoding` description, should make this more clear.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1e93770888d3e71422f9f8defab216f1ebf977c3/Documentation/config/gui.txt#L14):

> Specifies the default character encoding to use for displaying of

So `git config gui.encoding utf-8` refers to **[character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)**, a mean to represent a repertoire of characters by some kind of encoding system that assigns a number to each character for digital representation.
(As opposed to a [MIME Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding) like base64).