# How to change Git Locale config in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The french accents in my Git messages are not showing. I suppose the locale config is not well configured (as [Git messages with french accents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074014/2606835)).

However, I can't find the option to change the Git locale in Visual Studio Code.

**EDIT:** I'm using the French version of Visual Studio Code. I write my commits messages in the interface (Version Control in Visual Studio Code) and when I type `git log` in bash, it doesn't show me accents.

Comment: If you are in Europe (except eastern europe and greece) or US you most probably have it already as right as it can be, all of them use latin1 encoding. Probably you should instead specify more in which place of interface you see wrong symbols and how did you commit them.

Comment: @max630 I've edited my post to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: what "locale" prints in your bash?

Comment: probably this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416262/2303202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found that the problem was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320398/2606835).

I don't know why my French installation of Visual Studio Code didn't set the encoding by default but the problem was resolved by setting the encoding to UTF-8 for all repositories :

```
git config --global gui.encoding utf-8
```